# What is the difference between these ways when creating a function

Tags: javascript, function, object

When creating functions, What is the main difference and when to use these ways of creating a function?

```
onSubmit = () => {}

functionsName : () => {}
```

Comment: Both of those ways will cause syntax errors...

Comment: Are you sure `function : () => {}` is legal?

Comment: In an object, yes `{ function: () => {} }`

Comment: You are probably asking about [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) vs properties inside object literals

Comment: @ThumChoonTat yes can you explain the difference?

Comment: That code is still invalid. You can't create a variable called `function`

Comment: There is no difference. Both are errors.

Comment: @Samz you should change `function` to a valid identifier name (you're still going to face issues since `function` is a reserved keyword)

Comment: Please post your **actual code** where you found these two syntaxes. It's hard to tell without outer context. Are you using typescript by any chance? `:` could mean an object literal, a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) or a Typescript type

Comment: @NickParsons Sorry about that it should be the function name . I have updated

Comment: Still throwing errors.

Comment: Your latest edit doesn't solve the problem with the previous version of the question (the last code example still throws errors, you've just removed the live demo to make it harder to tell) but you've added a completely different question as the first example (which makes your question off-topic for a second reason ("Needs more focus")) (and it invalides the answer you've got because the first and second functions it talks about are now the second and third!)

Comment: Edited again with the actual function names

Comment: It's also best not to edit question such that the answers they've already received no longer apply, by adding a new and different example, changing the order referred to in the answer(s), and changing one of the options to a completely different (and invalid) construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference in the creation of the functions, just what is done with the function once it's created:

- Your `onSubmit` one creates a function and assigns it to an in-scope variable.
- Your `functionsName` one creates a function and assigns it to an object property. This form is only valid within an object initializer. (Outside of an object initializer, it's not a syntax error, but it's just a labelled statement and the function is never assigned to anything.)

You may find [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22173438/157247) useful as well. It's a rundown of various ways of creating functions.

Comment: Yes thanks by function i mean the function name i have updated it. Thanks for the answer